# why won't my fluentd work with elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker, fluentd

I am trying to collect docker log using fluentd and elasticsearch,Here are my logs starting fluentd.

```
2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: starting fluentd-0.12.19  
2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-config-placeholders' version '0.3.0'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-plaintextformatter' version '0.2.6'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '1.7.0'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '0.7.11'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '1.5.3'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '0.6.4'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-scribe' version '0.10.14'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-secure-forward' version '0.4.3'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '0.10.28'  
2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td-monitoring' version '0.2.1'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '0.4.1'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.12.19'  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: adding match pattern="td.*.*" type="tdlog"  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: adding match pattern="debug.**" type="stdout"  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: adding match pattern="docker.**" type="stdout"  

2016-11-30 16:29:34 +0800 [info]: adding match pattern="*.**" type="copy"  

2016-11-30 16:29:35 +0800 [info]: adding source type="forward"  
2016-11-30 16:29:35 +0800 [info]: adding source type="http"  
2016-11-30 16:29:35 +0800 [info]: adding source type="debug_agent"  
2016-11-30 16:29:35 +0800 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>  

  <match td.*.*>  
    type tdlog  
    apikey xxxxxx  
    auto_create_table  
    buffer_type file  
    buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/buffer/td  
    <secondary>  
      type file  
      path /var/log/td-agent/failed_records
      buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/failed_records.*
    </secondary>
  </match>
  <match debug.**>
    type stdout
  </match>
  <match docker.**>
    type stdout
  </match>
  <match *.**>
    type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host localhost
      port 9200
      include_tag_key true
      tag_key log_name
      logstash_format true
      flush_interval 1s
    </store>
  </match>
  <source>
    type forward
  </source>
  <source>
    type http
    port 8888
  </source>
  <source>
    type debug_agent
    bind 127.0.0.1
    port 24230
  </source>
</ROOT>

2016-11-30 16:29:35 +0800 [info]: listening fluent socket on 0.0.0.0:24224  
2016-11-30 16:29:35 +0800 [info]: listening dRuby uri="druby://127.0.0.1:24230" object="Engine"  
2016-11-30 16:29:38 +0800 docker.40271db2b565: {"log":"1:M 30 Nov 08:29:38.065 # User requested shutdown...","container_id":"40271db2b565d52fa0ab54bde2b0fa4b61e4ca033fca2b7edcf54c1a93443c19","container_name":"/tender_banach","source":"stdout"}
```

I using elasticsearch's default config,and after I started,it keep logging like this.

> [2016-11-30T16:49:32,154][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [I_hB3Vd] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [I_hB3VdfQ3q3hBeP5skTBQ][I_hB3Vd][/Users/it/Desktop/elasticsearch-5.0.1/data/nodes/0] free: 10gb[8.9%], shards will be relocated away from this node

My `elasticsearch` version is 5.0.1, `fluentd` version and `fluent-plugin-elasticsearch` is showed above. I'm using Mac OS 10.11.6. I've tried all the methods I could found online, anyone can offer a help?

Answer (score 0):

forgot to say my elasticsearch version is 5.0.1,and my fluentd version and fluent-plugin-elasticsearch is showed above, and I'm using Mac OS 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fluentd is starting just fine. I'd say it's a problem with your elasticsearch (data node if you have multiple nodes). The error says it ...looks like a disk space issue on one of your nodes.